# I want to extract specific char by using sed command

Tags: sed

I want to extract `/battle/result` from following the txt file

```
$ cat sample
user_id=1234 /battle/start
```

I run following the sed command

```
$ cat sample | sed 's|.*\(/.*\)|\1|g'
/start
```

But, result is deleting `/battle`, so I can't extract it as I want.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Is there any reason you insist on using `sed`?  `cut` and `awk` are more suited to this task.

Comment: However this sample can extract by using cut or awk, in fact I want to extract from access log for nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed tries to do a greedy (maximal) match, therefore `.*` matches your whole line up to but not including the second `/`.

Try:

```
< sample sed 's|.* \(/.*\)|\1|g'
```

or

```
< sample sed 's|[^/]*\(/.*\)|\1|g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all characters up to last space:

```
$ sed 's/.* //' <<< "user_id=1234 /battle/start"
/battle/start
```

or use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2 <<< "user_id=1234 /battle/start"
/battle/start
```

Answer (score 0):

In your RE the .* is greedy and swallows the `/battle` part, you could try to invert the logic and delete everything in front of `/`:

```
cat sample | sed 's/[^/]*//'
```

Here `[^/]*` matches everthing that is not a `/` and replaces it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  user_id=1234 /battle/start |grep -oP '\s\K.*'
/battle/start

echo  user_id=1234 /battle/start |sed -r 's/(^.*\s)(.*)/\2/g'
/battle/start
```